# What format does the default timestamps (create_at and updated_at) in laravel have when saved to db?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am about to save an additional timestamp to db: `last_sent`

I want to save it in the same way as the default timestamps (created_at and updated_at) - meaning that I am going to migrate it like so:

`$table->timestamp('last_sent')->nullable`
(It will be null sometimes..)

**My question is** what format on the time value should I save to this column?

I found two options but am not sure what is correct:

`Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();`

or just

`Carbon\Carbon::now();`

What is the correct way to save the date and time to get it like default timestamps?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `created_at` and `updated_at` look like?

Comment: It is the default timestamps in laravel, will clearify in post!

Comment: Sure but I could probably help you, except that I don't use laravel. Laravel isn't really relevant here, what matters is what the data looks like. If it's a raw number like `1591514175` then I could tell you it's just a timestamp so PHP's native `time()` function would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is a Mysql matter ...

according to [mysqltutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx)

> The MySQL TIMESTAMP is a temporal data type that holds the combination of date and time. The format of a TIMESTAMP is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS which is fixed at 19 characters.

so, the default is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

and this is how time Stamp stored in db ...

and if you find out what  $table->timestamps(); do it 's :

```
public function timestamps($precision = 0)
{
    $this->timestamp('created_at', $precision)->nullable();

    $this->timestamp('updated_at', $precision)->nullable();
}
```

so: laravel keep Mysql format with precision=0 by default
 if you want to store your column like default laravel time stamp you could:

```
$this->timestamp('last_sent',0)->nullable();
```

you can ignore second parameter

for values to your column:

```
Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
```

this won't do it because it's simple a string not a date

but this will be enough:

```
$value=Carbon\Carbon::now();
```

in spite of that $value will hold four number for milliseconds those number will be ignored in db because  of the (0 precision) in our migration ...

Comment: Thanks for answer. You are correct `Carbon\Carbon::now();` is the one to use

Comment: Starting from Laravel 7, the created_at column has a different format `2023-11-06T01:40:13.000000Z` details at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization also you can use `toJSON()` method to generate it like `Carbon\Carbon::now()->toJSON()`

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it is in YYYY-MM-DD Hour:Min:Sec format. To make you clear, I will add a screenshot for this.
[image]

I hope it will help you.

Comment: If using php's date function, this format's specification is date('Y-m-d H:i:s')